# How to target only checkboxes that are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm creating clones of checked input labels and outputting them in a header region. This is working as expected up until the form is submitted (it's using AJAX). I want to search for any inputs that were checked when the form was submitted and then recreate their clones.

The issue with the below code is that it is creating a clone for every input (all of which use the same class) irrespective of whether the input is checked or not. I assume that this is because the stuff inside the `if` is targeting all elements rather than just ones that are checked. When I use `$(this)` inside the `if` it doesn't appear to refer to only the elements that are checked and is instead an object.

How can I apply the stuff in the if statement to only those checkboxes that are checked?

```
if ($('.my-input').is(':checked')) {
  $('.my-input').next('label').clone().appendTo('.my-header');
  $('.my-input').next('label').addClass('is-checked');
}
```

Comment: use `:checked` selector like `$('.my-input:checked').next('label')`

Comment: You can use `$('.my-input:checked')`

Comment: use *$('.my-input:checked').each(function() {
    
});*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `checked` in `selector` `$('.my-input:checked')`

```
$('.my-input:checked').each(function() {
     $(this).next('label').clone().appendTo('.my-header');
     $(this).next('label').addClass('is-checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
$('.my-input:checked').each(function() {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to get all the checked checkboxes

```
$(":checkbox:checked")
```